# Woocommerce - hide product price when out of stock (not in admin)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to remove product prices from woocommerce out of stock products.

I've used this so far (in the functions.php) :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'remove_price_ofs', 10, 2 );
function remove_price_ofs( $price, $product ) {
if ( ! $product->is_in_stock()) {$price = '';}
return $price;
}
```

The problem is that it's also hiding the price in the orders admin list. How can I avoid that ?

Thanks !

Comment: `if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() && ! is_admin() ) { ...` Just check to make sure you're not in the admin area `! is_admin()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check for it.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'remove_price_ofs', 10, 2 );

function remove_price_ofs( $price, $product ) {
   if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() && (is_product() || is_product_category() || is_shop() ) ) {$price = '';}
   return $price;
}
```

### OPTION 2

To run only on frontend.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'remove_price_ofs', 10, 2 );

function remove_price_ofs( $price, $product ) {
   if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() && ! is_admin() ) {$price = '';}
   return $price;
}
```

We just check if its a product page and if it is then only we change the price. You might want to do this for archive pages as well.

> List of conditional tags you can use.
> https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/

Comment: Actually, I don't need to do this in single product page but archive page and I can't find any condition for products archives page

Comment: @AlexisK I have updated the answer. This should work on single page, shop page and archive page.

Comment: Na, I've tried using is_shop(), is_product_category() individually before your answer and I've tried your code also but it still doesn't hide the price in the archive page :(

And the price is hidden in the admin panel too (in the products listing, not orders listing btw)

Comment: Are you sure its an archive page and not some other page. What's the URL ?

Comment: @AlexisK, I have also added one more option. Try that, it just checks if the request is coming from admin or not and if it isn't then it changes the product price HTML>

Comment: Your option 2 is working perfectly ! Thanks a lot

Comment: @AlexisK, consider marking this as the correct answer. This is how you do it. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147532/1004134